# reading of ODBC failed after converting date to decimal

Tags: sql, date, decimal, qlikview

I am working in Qlikview on a database with a lot of dates.
I need to convert a date to a decimal value so I can calculate a % of total travel time in a particular month (eg 3 /30 days = 10%).
However when I do a `CONVERT(DECIMAL(20,10),YY.Transit_Days)` it states that it failed to connect to ODBC.
When I remove `CONVERT`, everything works fine, but i/o 3 days it shows a date in 1900.
Note: I am working on a read-only database (don't know if that has any effect).

Comment: Pot up your data structure with some sample data please

Comment: Hi Matt I found what was wrong. I had the same name in a table within a table. Apparently that causes a critical crash !

Comment: Excellent, post your solution as an answer so in the future people can find it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. I had the same name in a table within a table. Apparently that causes a critical crash !
I juste needed to name the variable differently.